# How to run app on secondly added device with eclipse android?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

As in topic, first is emulator, secondly added is device. All the time I run the application it shows how it cannot install the app because it has installed due to the fact it does not even try to install on secondly added device.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can go to **Run** > Select your project in **Android Applications**  > Select **Target** tab and select **Always prompt to pick device**

Now, if you run the application project, Eclipse will show you list of all connected devices. Select the device on which you want to run the app :)

Good Luck!